# Left hand mouse

Tags: mouse, windows-11

I found a setting for the mouse that lets me configure the "Primary mouse button". This works well in Windows. However, this seems to be a Windows setting, not a mouse driver setting: In video games the setting is not respected.

How can I make the mouse transparently left handed?

Background: I'm not actually left handed, but want to suspend right hand mouse usage temporarily due to a medical condition. Searching the Internet revealed tips like resoldering the buttons in the mouse itself... Since there are lots of actual left handed people in the world, I expected this to be a simple setting I could change conviniently.

Answer (score 0):

Highrez's [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) is a free application that hooks into the mouse messaging system at a low level and can switch buttons and other controls. It's also configurable for multiple profiles (layers), so when your right hand recovers, you can occasionally shift back to "lefty" to reduce the strain on one hand. There are other [alternative applications](https://alternativeto.net/software/x-mouse-button-control/), too.

[image: X-Mouse Button Control]

Hopefully, this hooks in at a *low enough* level for a game to accept that input translation... please post back if this works, or not, for those games.

BTW, use an "ambidextrous" mouse, such as the Logitech M510 or Lenovo GX30M39704 300. Some are distressingly biased to one hand or the other!

Comment: On the one hand this looks very interesting, I am however very hesitant to install software from some website on my PC.

Comment: And I'm still surprised that this isn't something Microsoft has addressed themeselves. I figure left handed people to be a large enough minority not to be ignored by Microsoft.

Comment: @user1785730, you are correct in being circumspect... check *everything* before running or installing against VirusTotal, https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload, which uses over 60 creditable anti-malware apps to check safety.